# Routing Call in Flask leads towards 404 when index routing works

Tags: python, apache, flask, peewee, amazon-ami

I'm having trouble trying to route URLs in Flask using an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) Apache, and Peewee.  Essentially, I'm trying to use a GET to retrieve database content and a POST to insert data into the database.  Index routing ("/") works but after that, /api sends to a Method Not allowed and other calls simply do not work with /api/1 getting a 404 error and /api/random+string/1 also getting a 404.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                               
import re, os, sys, time, shutil, numpy, cgi, cgitb, json, peewee, playhouse
from peewee import *
from flask import *
cgitb.enable()
mainapp = Flask(__name__)
###Some code here
@mainapp.route("/api/<int:task_id>", methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    try:
            j = R.get(R.rid ==task_id)
    except R.DoesNotExist:
            print "aborting because it doens't exist"
            abort(400)
    ##3Take data into Json ready format
    db.close()
    return jsonify(##Json format)

@mainapp.route('/')

curl -i website/api/1
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:52:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) PHP/5.6.26 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12
Content-Length: 233
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went and modified the wsgi file to make sure it was properly importing.  I also went to restart httpd (apache) to make sure that the file "synced" and that it was running properly.  Finally, I went through the error logs to make sure that my code was correct and that seemed to work.